# Camel-Azure BlobServiceProducer IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported blob type:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile

Tags: apache-camel

I have written a camel route which polls a folder and sends it to Azure Blob Container

I followed the example mentioned in the Azure document page
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-azure/src/main/docs/azure-blob-component.adoc

I am reversing the route. Instead of a consumer, I am using the Azure Blob Producer.
This is  my route. I have used Java DSL.

```
from("file://C:/camel/source1").to("azure-blob://datastorage/container1/BLOB1?credentials=#credentials&operation=updateBlockBlob")
```

When I placed a file, I got the following error.

```
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported blob type:org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFile
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceProducer.getInputStreamFromExchange(BlobServiceProducer.java:474) ~[camel-azure-2.19.2.jar:2.19.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceProducer.updateBlockBlob(BlobServiceProducer.java:143) ~[camel-azure-2.19.2.jar:2.19.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.azure.blob.BlobServiceProducer.process(BlobServiceProducer.java:79) ~[camel-azure-2.19.2.jar:2.19.2]**
```

I was able to fix this. I rewrote my route as.

```
    from("file://C:/camel/source1")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    Object file = exchange.getIn().getMandatoryBody();

                    exchange.getOut().setBody(
                            GenericFileConverter.genericFileToInputStream(
                                    (GenericFile<?>) file, exchange));
                }
            })
            .to("azure-blob://datastorage/container1/BLOB1?credentials=#credentials&operation=updateBlockBlob")
            .to("mock:Result");
```

My Question is, do I need to really write the processor? Shouldn't the camel component be receiving a stream or a File Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is a little bug. I have logged a ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-11844

You can do the workaround you did, or you can add a .convertBodyTo and convert to a FileInputStream, String etc.

```
 from("file://C:/camel/source1")
     .convertBodyTo(String.class)
     ...
```

Comment: Is there a way I can do this via an interceptor? I tried but I have multiple routes, where I list blob and also update blobs. Want to do only if it is a azure-blob and operation=update. Guess might have to use some regex to do so

Comment: You can use interceptSendToEndpoint("azure*") and then add the covertBodyTo. See more details at: http://camel.apache.org/intercept

Comment: will this cause any performance issue? Because I need to send it to azure, i think using a splitter won't help right. sorry I am going off topic

Comment: The interceptSendToEndpoint wont cause performance issue, it will intercept when Camel buildup the routes and add that .convertBodyTo as inlined, as if you had typed that yourself. But for any performance related thing, ask the computer - eg do your own testing and compare.